# How can i rotate my custom Marker(rotation doesn't work)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import airplane from '../airplane.svg';

<Marker
     position={position}
     onMouseDown={() => setShowContent(true)}
     icon={{
        url: airplane,
        anchor: new window.google.maps.Point(35, 40),
        rotation: rot,
          }}
           }
        ></Marker>
```

How to rotate this marker?
Mb with sprites.
Mb can someone explain how to do that